# Laravel: How to Append Properties to an Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have an array that gets returned from my `show` method. This is the show method:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $track = Fuelconsumption::where('id', $id)->first();

    return $track;
}
```

Returns this:

```
{
    id: 6,
    distance: 178.6,
    volume: 14.31,
    price: 1.45,
    date: "2015-11-08 14:13:56",
    created_at: "2015-11-30 03:29:57",
    updated_at: "2015-11-30 03:29:57"
}
```

I want to make some calculations (averages etc.) from the values provided and append these variables to above json array.

Right now I am solving the problem, by creating a `new Kpi` object in a new `KpiController`. The controller passes the above `array` (which is a FuelConsumption Object) to my `constructor`.

This is the `show` method of my `KpiController`:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $item = Fuelconsumption::where('id', $id)->first();

    $kpi = new Kpi($item);

    return $kpi['list'];
}
```

`Constructor` of my `Kpi` class:

```
protected $avgFuel;
protected $avgCost;
protected $cost;
protected $list;

/**
 * Creates all necessary KPIs
 * 
 * @param Object $item Fuelconsumption
 */
public function __construct(Fuelconsumption $item)
{
    $this->avgFuel = $this->avgFuelperUnitofDistance($item);
    $this->avgCost = $this->avgCostPerUnitOfDistance($item);
    $this->cost = $this->cost($item);

    $this->list = [
        'avgFuelperUnitOfDistance' => $this->avgFuel, 
        'avgCostperUnitOfDistance' => $this->avgCost,
        'cost' => $this->cost
    ];
}
```

And it returns a Json array that looks like this:

```
{
     avgFuelperUnitOfDistance: 0.08,
     avgCostperUnitOfDistance: 0.116,
     cost: 20.75
}
```

---

The problem I have now is that the first array gets returned when I visit the following URI:

```
http://localhost:8000/fuelconsumption/6
```

And the second array gets returned when I visit this URI:

```
http://localhost:8000/fuelconsumption/6/kpi
```

The problem is that I want both Json Arrays to be combined in one Array and I am not sure how to accomplish this.

---

**HERE ARE MY THOUGHTS:**

**Modify Fuelconsumption Class**

Modify my FuelConsumptionController to this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $item = Fuelconsumption::where('id', $id)->first();

    $kpi = new Fuelconsumption($item);

    dd($kpi);
}
```

And have a constructor in my `Fuelconsumption` class:

```
class Fuelconsumption extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['distance', 'volume', 'price', 'date'];

    protected $dates = ['date'];

    protected $cost;

    public function __construct($item) {
        $this->cost = $this->cost($item);
    }

    public function cost($item) {
        return round($item->volume * $item->price, 2);
    }
}
```

This unfortunately throws the error:

> Missing argument 1 for App\Fuelconsumption::__construct()

In my understanding because the class is called even before I recall it in my controller a 2nd time. Not sure how to solve this.

**Second Thought: Expand the KPI object**

To include all other variables I want to have and then somehow return in my FuelConsumptionController@show method the complete array.

**Third Thought: Somehow combine these arrays**

Not sure how.

---

Right now I believe the easiest solution would be to expand on the KPI model (Second Thought of mine), yet I hoped to get rid of the KPI class altogether by somehow passing the `item` to my `FuelConsumption` constructor.

Comment: check this - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a solution to your suggestion. I would appreciate any advice, compared to the other solution provided by Yorm de Langen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your almost right.. because your class `FuelConsumption` is an Eloquent model the `__construct` is already been setup by Laravel and your tried to override it.

What Eloquent does is in case of using `->first()` or `->find($id)` returning a single model (like what you have). When using `->all()` or `->get()` it is returning a Eloquent Collection.

Suggestible approach:

```
class Fuelconsumption extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['distance', 'volume', 'price', 'date'];

    protected $dates = ['date'];

    protected $cost;

    public function cost() {
        return round($this->volume * $this->price, 2);
    }

    public function avgFuelperUnitofDistance() {
        return $this->distance / $volume; // do your thing, dummy calc
    }

    public function avgCostPerUnitOfDistance() {
        return $this->distance / $price;  // do your thing, dummy calc
    }
}
```

And your api controller method could look like:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $item = Fuelconsumption::find($id)->first();
    // if $item == null if it is item was not found
    if (!$item) {
        return response('item was missing', 404);
    }

    // $item will look like:
    // class Fuelconsumption: {
    //    id: 6,
    //    distance: 178.6,
    //    volume: 14.31,
    //    price: 1.45,
    //    date: "2015-11-08 14:13:56",
    //    created_at: "2015-11-30 03:29:57",
    //    updated_at: "2015-11-30 03:29:57"
    // }

    // doing more stuff over here

    // create the json response
    return response()->json([
        'id' => $item->id,
        'distance' => $item->distance,
        'volume' => $item->volume,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'date' => $item->date,
        'cost' => $item->cost(),
        'avg_fuel' => $item->avgFuelperUnitofDistance(),
        'avg_unit' => $item->avgCostperUnitofDistance(),
    ]);
}
```

or if you really want to create and merge the attributes:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $item = Fuelconsumption::find($id)->first();

    .....

    $extra = [
        'cost' => $item->cost(),
        'avg_fuel' => $item->avgFuelperUnitofDistance(),
        'avg_unit' => $item->avgCostperUnitofDistance(),
    ];

    return array_merge($item->getAttributes(), $extra);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Could you also have a look on the solution I wrote thanks to user naneri, because I try to figure laravel out.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve it would be the suggestion by user naneri with this link:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Then my model would look like this:

```
class Fuelconsumption extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['distance', 'volume', 'price', 'date'];

    protected $dates = ['date'];

    protected $appends = ['cost', 'avg_fuel_per_unit_of_distance', 'avg_cost_per_unit_of_distance'];

    public function getCostAttribute()
    {
        return round($this->attributes['volume'] * $this->attributes['price'], 2);
    }

    public function getAvgFuelPerUnitOfDistanceAttribute()
    {
        return round($this->attributes['volume'] / $this->attributes['distance'], 3 );
    }

    public function getAvgCostPerUnitOfDistanceAttribute()
    {
        return round($this->attributes['volume'] * $this->attributes['price'] / $this->attributes['distance'], 3);
    }

}
```

And the output of my `show` method would look like this when getting the URI `http://localhost:8000/fuelconsumption/6`

```
{
    id: 6,
    distance: 178.6,
    volume: 14.31,
    price: 1.45,
    date: "2015-11-08 14:13:56",
    created_at: "2015-11-30 03:29:57",
    updated_at: "2015-11-30 03:29:57",
    cost: 20.75,
    avg_fuel_per_unit_of_distance: 0.08,
    avg_cost_per_unit_of_distance: 0.116
}
```

Comment: Only suggestion is to change the name `date` to something else... what kind of date is it (maybe something like: registered_at)? `date` is a reserved word

Comment: To Shorten the code: `$this->attributes['...']` to `$this->...` example:
`public function getCostAttribute()
{
    return round($this->volume * $this->price, 2);
}

public function getAvgFuelPerUnitOfDistanceAttribute()
{
    return round($this->volume / $this->distance, 3 );
}

public function getAvgCostPerUnitOfDistanceAttribute()
{
    return round($this->volume * $this->price / $this->distance, 3);
}
`